# Proguard - How to resolve org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated exception?

Tags: exception, jar, glassfish, proguard, obfuscation

I am new to obfuscating the code. I am using Proguard for obfuscating one big fat mycompanyrepo.jar file (75MB). I did create a proguard.cfg file and put proguard options such as -injar, -outjar, -libraryjars, -dontwarn, -ignorewarnings, -keep options, etc to make sure the build is successful. The new mycompany-obfuscated.jar is generated. I deployed it in Vagrant VM and it started throwing exception such as below while using functionalities. Basically, it's broken. I extracted the mycompany-obfuscated.jar and looked inside it to see what classes are obfuscated by proguard and it appears it pretty much obfuscated every lib jar including com.mycompany.mysrc package. I am trying to resolve below exception which I am not sure how to resolve it. In the exploded mycompany-obfuscated.jar, I can see pretty much all the folders and see the specific class such as org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl that it throws the exception about.

Below is the proguard.cfg file, and exception detail.

Proguard.cfg

```
-injars C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\t1\mycompany.jar
-outjars C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\t1\mycompany-obfuscate.jar

-keep class org.python.core.** { *; }
-keep class **Cookie$py { *; }
-keep class org.python.core.PyObject { *; }
-keep class org.python.core.ThreadState { *; }

-keep class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.** { *; 
-keep interface org.glassfish.jersey.internal.** { *; }
-keep class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl { *; }
-keep class org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities { *; }
-keep class org.glassfish.hk2.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface org.glassfish.hk2.internal.** { *; }
-keep class java.lang.reflect.** { *; }
-keep class sun.reflect.** { *; }
-keep class java.lang.** { *; }
-keep class org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient { *; }
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames  
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses 
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers 
-useuniqueclassmembername
-dontoptimize
-adaptresourcefilenames

-dontwarn org.springframework.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn net.sf.**
-dontwarn com.jcraft.**
-dontwarn com.codehale.**
-dontwarn com.ctc.**
-dontwarn org.python.**
-dontwarn org.owasp.**
-dontwarn storm.kafka.**
-dontwarn backtype.storm.**
-dontwarn clojure.**
-dontwarn io.netty.**
-dontwarn com.xhaus.**
-dontwarn org.python.core.Py.**
-dontwarn mathexpressions.** 
-dontwarn mpmath.** 
-dontwarn org.python.__init__$py
-dontwarn mathexpressions.__init__$py
-dontnote javax.xml.xpath.**
-dontnote org.jcp.xml.dsig.**
-dontnote org.w3c.dom.**
-dontnote org.xml.sax.**
-dontnote javax.xml.parsers.**
-dontnote javax.activation.**
-dontnote javax.xml.crypto.**
-dontnote javax.xml.XMLConstants**
-dontnote javax.xml.datatype.**
-dontnote javax.xml.namespace.**
-dontnote javax.xml.stream.**
-dontnote javax.xml.transform.**
-dontnote javax.xml.validation.**
-dontnote com.sun.activation.**
-dontnote javax.annotation.**
-dontnote javax.transaction.**
-dontnote javax.activation.**

-dontwarn com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.**
-dontwarn com.ziclix.python.sql.**
-dontwarn org.glassfish.**
-dontwarn org.xerial.**
-dontwarn com.sun.org.**
-dontwarn com.sun.beans.**
-dontwarn com.sun.istack.**
-dontwarn com.sun.xml.internal.**
-dontwarn javax.util.prefs.**
-dontwarn javax.imageio.**
-dontwarn javax.swing.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.bind.**
-dontwarn jline.**
-dontwarn org.jcp.xml.**
-dontwarn com.datastax.driver.core.**
-dontwarn com.mycompany.dmip.script.datatype.converter.**
-dontwarn com.kenai.**
-dontwarn javaassist.util.**
-dontwarn javax.cache.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.mail.**
-dontwarn org.joda.**
-dontwarn org.opensaml.xml.**
-dontwarn org.quartz.jobs.**
-dontwarn javax.sql.**
-dontwarn com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.**
-dontwarn com.sun.rowset.**
-dontwarn java.util.prefs.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.crypto.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.soap.**
-dontwarn sun.util.xml.**
-dontwarn com.netflix.**
-dontwarn com.sun.xml.bind.v3.runtime.output.**
-dontwarn com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.**
-dontwarn com.ziclix.python.sql.**
-dontwarn javassist.util.**
-dontwarn kafka.admin.**
-dontwarn org.opensaml.common.binding.artifact.**
-dontwarn org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.**
-dontwarn org.opensaml.common.impl.**
-dontwarn java.sql.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.transform.**

-ignorewarnings

-keepattributes *Annotation*,Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,EnclosingMethod

-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}


-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
                native <methods>;
}
-printseeds
-printmapping proguard.map
-verbose
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at com.mycompany.dmip.common.builder.a.b.b(Unknown Source) ~[job-builder.jar:?]
        at com.mycompany.dmip.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source) ~[job-builder.jar:?]
        at com.mycompany.dmip.common.builder.manager.JobBuilderManager.b(Unknown Source) ~[job-builder.jar:?]
        at com.mycompany.dmip.common.builder.manager.JobBuilderManager.main(Unknown Source) [job-builder.jar:?]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.a.e(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.a.find(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructo`enter code here`r.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.a.e(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.a.find(Unknown Source) ~[dmipDPC.jar:?]
        ... 11 more
```